# Why doesn't uint8_t and int8_t work with file and console streams?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, ifstream, uint8t

```
$ file testfile.txt
testfile.txt: ASCII text

$ cat testfile.txt 
aaaabbbbccddef

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
typedef uint8_t byte; // <-------- interesting
typedef std::basic_ifstream<byte> FileStreamT;
static const std::string FILENAME = "testfile.txt";
int main(){
    FileStreamT file(FILENAME, std::ifstream::in | std::ios::binary);
    if(!file.is_open())
        std::cout << "COULD NOT OPEN FILE" << std::endl;
    else{
        FileStreamT::char_type buff;
        file.read(&buff,1);
        std::cout << (SOMECAST)buff; // <------- interesting
    }
    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
}
```

Depending on what is in the typedef and what is it casted to (or not casted), it does all sorts of stupid things.

It happens to work with 'typedef char' and no cast. (97 when casted to int, as expected)

Both uint8_t and int8_t will print

- nothing without cast
- nothing when casted to char or unsigned char
- 8 when casted to int or unsigned (although ASCII 'a' should be 97)

I somehow managed to print a "�" character, but forgot which case it was.

Why do I get these strange results?

### notes for the future reader:

takeaway from the answer given: only instantiate streams with char (or one of the wide characters also mentioned by the standard), otherwise you get no compiler warning and silent failure

it is very sad that the standard warrants these things

## moral of the story: avoid C++

Comment: `uint8_t` is a typedef of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Rapptz: what you linked is helpful, thanks, remark: uint8_t is not by definition equivalent to unsigned char, it just happens to be the most common way of implementing it in the cstdint header

Comment: @Rapptz: But that question did not answer everything I asked. Especially why am I getting the number 8, instead of 97. And I would like someone to confirm that typedef influences whether template specialization gets chosen or not.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can emulate this with using `int8_t` rather than `uint8_t`?

Comment: typedef int8_t byte; ...; cout << buff << endl << (char)buff << endl << (int)buff << endl; results in � � -73

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration of `template std::basic_ifstream` is:

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
> class basic_ifstream;
```

The C++03 Standard (21.1/1) requires the library to define specializations
of `std::char_traits<CharT>` for `CharT` = `char`, `wchar_t`.

The C++11 Standard (C++11 21.2/1) requires the library to define specializations
of `std::char_traits<CharT>` for `CharT` = `char`,`char16_t`,`char32_t`,`wchar_t`.

If you instantiate `std::basic_ifstream<Other>` with `Other` not one of
the 2[4] types nominated by the Standard to which you are compiling then
the behaviour will be undefined, unless you yourself
define `my_char_traits<Other>` as you require and then instantiate
`std::basic_ifstream<Other,my_char_traits<Other>>`.

**CONTINUED** in response to OP's comments.

Requesting an `std::char_traits<Other>` will not provoke template instantiation
errors: the template is defined *so that you may specialize it*, but the
default (unspecialized) instantiation is very likely to be *wrong* for `Other` 
or indeed for any given `CharT`, where *wrong* means *does not satisfy the
the Standard's requirements for a character traits class per C++03 § 21.1.1/C++11 § 21.2.1*.

You suspect that a typedef might thwart the choice of a template specialization 
for the `typedef`-ed type, i.e. that the fact that `uint8_t` and `int8_t`
are typedefs for fundamentals character types might result in `std::basic_ifstream<byte>`
not being the same as `std::basic_ifstream<FCT>`, where *FCT*
is the aliased fundamental character type.

Forget that suspicion.`typedef` is transparent. It seems you believe *one* of 
the typedefs `int8_t` and `uint8_t` must be `char`,  in which case - unless
the typedef was somehow intefering with template resolution - 
one of the misbehaving `basic_ifstream` instantiations you have tested would
have to be `std::basic_ifstream<char>`

But what about the fact that `typedef char byte` is harmless? That belief that
either `int8_t` or `uint8_t` = `char` is false. You will find that `int8_t` 
is an alias for `signed char`  while `uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`. 
But neither `signed char` nor `unsigned char` is the same type as `char`:

C++03/11 § 3.9.1/1

> Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types

So both `char_traits<int8_t>` and `char_traits<uint8_t>` are default,
unspecialized, instantiations of template `char_traits` and you have
no right to expect that they fulfill that Standard's requirements of
*character traits*.

The one test case in which you found no misbehaviour was for `byte` = `char`.
That is because `char_traits<char>` is a Standard specialization provided
by the library.

The connection between all the misbehaviour you have observed and the
types that you have substituted for `SOMECAST` in:

```
std::cout << (SOMECAST)buff; // <------- interesting
```

is none. Since your testfile contains ASCII text, `basic_ifstream<char>`
is the one and only instantiation of `basic_ifstream` that the Standard warrants
for reading it. If you read the file using `typedef char byte` in your program
then none of the casts that you say you substituted will have an unexpected
result: `SOMECAST` = `char` or `unsigned char` will output `a`, and
`SOMECAST` = `int` or `unsigned int` will output `97`.

All the misbehaviour arises from instantiating `basic_ifstream<CharT>` with `CharT`
some type that the Standard does not warrant.

Comment: but my Other type was a typedef of char in one of the test cases and it failed silently, I did not get template instantiation errors (used -std=c++0x with g++ 4.6.3), ? do typedefs prohibit proper template specialization ?